# typedef in C++ where original name is same as alias

Tags: c++, typedef

Based on my little bit of learning `typedef` is used to create an alias. But I see code where the "alias" is the exact same name as the original. What is the use here?

e.g.

```
typedef struct Dog{
  bool hasLegs;
} Dog;
```

Comment: This is a C-ism/just plain C code.  I've closed to a dupe that explains why this is done.  In C++, this is totally unneeded and the class can just be written as `struct Dog { bool hasLegs; };`

Comment: You do it in C so you don't have to write `struct Dog` everywhere and you can just go with `Dog`. It's just to make things easier. (I'm not sure of the use in C++ but I guess its similar)

Comment: @JakubBednarski Same use in C++, but C++ built this behaviour in by default making the `typedef` trick redundant. Still useful if you need to write interop code, though.

Comment: For this particular struct, in C all that would be needed (snoring the non-C `bool`) is `typedef struct { bool hasLegs; } Dog;`.